# How to set correct frame to custom view?

Tags: ios

I am adding a custom view (`MainComponentView`) to user controller. Now in `MainComponentView` I am also adding a custom view (`FirstPartView`) and `FirstPartView`'s height should be less than `MainComponentView`'s height. My problem is that when I give less height to `MainComponentView` than `FirstPartView` height, it is still showing me the whole view of `FirstPartView`.

```
// MainComponentView
self.aComponent = [[MainComponentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(212, 0, 600, 550)
                                             withStartDate:startDate
                                                   endDate:endDate];
[self.view addSubview:self.aComponent];
```

and to add the custom view to `MainComponentView` :

```
self.aFirPartView = [[FirPartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, HEIGHT_OF_COMPONENT1) withStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate]; 
[self addSubview:self.aFirPartView];`
```

Comment: oh yes!!!one minute.....

Comment: To add MainComponentView:self.aComponent = [[MainComponentView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(212, 0, 600, 550) withStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate];
    [self.view addSubview:self.aComponent]; and To add custom view in MainComponentView : self.aFirPartView = [[FirPartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, HEIGHT_OF_COMPONENT1) withStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate];
    
    [self addSubview:self.aFirPartView];

Comment: Edit the question and paste it there please. It's so hard to follow like this.

Comment: @Desdenova and sunny : please help me or give me any hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
self.aComponent.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

To tell the view that it should not draw any part of any subview which is outside of its frame.

Answer (score 0):

Subview coordinates are relative to the superview, not to the window, so when you do this:

```
self.aFirPartView = [[FirPartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, HEIGHT_OF_COMPONENT1) withStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate]; 
[self addSubview:self.aFirPartView];`
```

the view you create is offset downwards by the distance of the `MainComponentView` from the top of the screen.

Try using this frame value instead:

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, HEIGHT_OF_COMPONENT1)
```

This will position the subview at the top left corner of your `MainComponentView`, with the specified width and height.